# ReactJS: value of the object is undefined

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I'm trying to make an application that shows Covid 19 numbers. I want to show global numbers when the component is rendered, so I used useEffect hooks for this. When I try to display `global.confirmed` it's returns an object but when I try to display `global.confirmed.value` I get a `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` error. How can I fix this?

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [countries, SetCountries] = useState([]);
  const [cases, SetCases] = useState([]);
  const [global, SetGlobal] = useState({});

  const urlGlobal = "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/"
  const urlCountries = "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/";

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(urlGlobal).then(res => SetGlobal(res.data))
    axios.get(urlCountries).then((res) => SetCountries(res.data.countries));
  }, []);

  const showCases = (e) => {
    const urlCases = `https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/${e.target.value}`;
    axios.get(urlCases).then((res) => SetCases(res.data));
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>Infected</p>
        <p>{cases.confirmed.value}</p>
        <p>{cases.lastUpdate}</p>
        <p>Number of active cases of COVID-19</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Recovered</p>
        <p>{cases.recovered.value}</p>
        <p>{cases.lastUpdate}</p>
        <p>Number of recoveries from COVID-19</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Deaths</p>
        <p>{cases.deaths.value}</p>
        <p>{cases.lastUpdate}</p>
        <p>Number of deaths caused by COVID-19</p>
      </div>
      <select name="countries" onChange={(e) => showCases(e)}>
        {countries.map((val, i) => (
          <option key={i} value={val.name}>
            {val.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

global:
[image]

Comment: What happened when you display `cases.confirmed` ? You said you were getting an object but can you see if there is any field inside ?

Comment: When your component first mounts, the data hasn’t been fetched yet. So on the first render `cases` is the empty array you passed to `useState`.

Comment: @Maxime I added the screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default you set `cases` to an empty array:

```
const [cases, SetCases] = useState([]);
```

And on the initial render, while it's still an empty array, you try to access properties which aren't defined on an array:

```
<p>{cases.confirmed.value}</p>
```

There are essentially two problems here:

1. Arrays don't have properties like `confirmed`.  Do you expect `cases` to be an object instead?
2. When the component first renders, `cases` has no data, so don't attempt to display that data.

Let `cases` start off `undefined` (since in the usage it looks like it shouldn't even be an array):

```
const [cases, SetCases] = useState();
```

And only display it when it's not `undefined`:

```
<div>
  <p>Infected</p>
  <p>{cases && cases.confirmed.value}</p>
  <p>{cases && cases.lastUpdate}</p>
  <p>Number of active cases of COVID-19</p>
</div>
```

You can repeat for other usages, or wrap all of the usages in a single check for `cases`:

```
{
  cases &&
  <div>
    <p>Infected</p>
    <p>{cases.confirmed.value}</p>
    <p>{cases.lastUpdate}</p>
    <p>Number of active cases of COVID-19</p>
  </div>
}
```

The idea is that these elements won't even try to render if `cases` is "falsey" (which `undefined` is), so the code won't try to access properties like `confirmed` until `cases` exists.

---

**However**, *if* `cases` *should* be an array, then what you also have is a logical error in your overall markup structure because arrays don't have properties like `confirmed`.  Perhaps you meant to calculate values from within the array.  If that's the case then you can keep the initial state as an empty array:

```
const [cases, SetCases] = useState([]);
```

But you'd need to change your markup to something that uses an array.  For example, maybe something like:

```
{
  cases.map(c => (
    <div>
      <p>Infected</p>
      <p>{c.confirmed.value}</p>
      <p>{c.lastUpdate}</p>
      <p>Number of active cases of COVID-19</p>
    </div>
  ))
}
```

I'm not entirely familiar with the data you're using or how you want it displayed, but a key consideration here is simply the difference between an object and an array of objects.  Which you'll need to determine in your code.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote cases instead of global but I understand your point. I tried to use `{global && global.confirmed.value} ` and `{global !== undefined && global.confirmed.value}` but still giving the same error. Btw I tried this for the cases too and it's still same.

Comment: @poena9191: In your `useState` initialization of `global` you're setting it to an object: `{}`.  Did you change that to not set it to anything?  Otherwise you'll be getting the same error for the same reason.  The empty object `{}` has no property called `confirmed`.  It's basically always the same pattern... Whatever is `undefined` (whether it's the object itself, a property on the object, etc.), you need to check if it's defined before trying to use it.

Comment: I did it now and it worked. I thought we have to define empty array or object for the first time if data is array or object. Should I delete the array ones too?

Comment: @poena9191: You can define the initial value however you see fit, there's no one rule for all cases of that.  For example, if you have an array then you can define an empty array initially and then your render can always safely iterate the array, knowing that it'll simply have no iterations for an empty array.  Or if you have meaningful default values for an object then you can define that default object literal.  It's really up to you what you want your initial values to be.